# jqGrid is not loading data

Tags: jqgrid

I am using jqGrid for my data table solution. Below are the configuration codes.

```
$(function() {
    $("#submitInput").click(function() {
        alert("I am called...")
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            datatype: "json",
            url: "http://localhost:1201/admin/someURL.htm",
            mtype:"POST",
            height: "auto",
            colNames:["Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3", "Column 4", "Column 5"],
            colModel:[
                {name:"col1", index:"col1", sortable:true, resizable:false},
                {name:"col2", index:"col2", sortable:true},
                {name:"col3", index:"col3", sortable:false, resizable:false},
                {name:"col4", index:"col4", sortable:true, resizable:false},
                {name:"col5", index:"col5", sortable:true, resizable:false}
            ],
            sortname:'col1',
            sortorder:'asc',
            pager: $('#pager'),
            rowNum:10,
            viewrecords: true,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            caption: 'Some Grid Values',
            jsonReader: {
                root: "responseData",
                page: "currentPage",
                total: "totalPages",
                records: "totalFetchedRecords",
                repeatitems: true,
                cell: "rowContent",
                id: "rowID"
            },
            gridComplete: function() {
                alert("Loading done...");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My JSON data is coming in the following format:

```
"currentPage":"1","responseData":[
    {"rowContent":["Col1_Val_000001","Col2_Val_1","Col3_Val_1","Col4_Val_1","Col5_Val_1"],"rowID":"Col1_Val_000001"},
    {"rowContent":["Col1_Val_000002","Col2_Val_2","Col3_Val_2","Col4_Val_2","Col5_Val_2"],"rowID":"Col1_Val_000002"}
], "totalFetchedRecords":"50","totalPages":"5"}
```

In my HTML, there is a button with id "submitInput" and a table with id "list".

Somehow, this data is not loaded into the grid. What is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should don't create jqGrid inside of **click** handle. You should do this one time outside of **click** handle and call `jQuery("list").trigger('reloadGrid')` inside of the handler. If at the beginning the data should be not loaded in the grid, you can use `datatype: 'local'` an the beginning. If it needed, you can makes *div* with jqGrid sometimes visitable and sometimes invisible using using `hide()` and `show()` jQuery functions. Inside of `click` handler you can change the `datatype` to `'json'` with respect of `setGridParam()` and then call `trigger('reloadGrid')`. In a lot of situation you also change some parameters of URL before calling `trigger('reloadGrid')` (see [Should one replace the usage addJSONData of jqGrid to the usage of setGridParam(), and trigger('reloadGrid')?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660226/should-one-replace-the-usage-addjsondata-of-jqgrid-to-the-usage-of-setgridparam)), but probably you need it not in your case.