# How to disable autoload in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, autoload, manual

How to disable autoload in jqGrid and load data manually when I need it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you set `datatype` to `'local'` the data from the server will be not loaded. To force the loading of data you can change `datatype` to `'json'` or `'xml'` with respect of `setGridParam` method (see http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options and http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#grid_related_methods) and then call `trigger("reloadGrid")` method.

See [jqGrid is not loading data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703369/jqgrid-is-not-loading-data/2703518#2703518) which has also the information what you asked.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't set the default URL in the table. And install it just  when you need to load data (for example by pressing a button) and then  `.trigger("reloadGrid")`.

Example for you:

```
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid(
         { 
            //Simply comment out the URL
            //url             :"salepointsprovider.php", 
            datatype:"json",
            colModel      :[
                {name:'SalePointId', index:'SalePointId'},
                {name:'Name', index:'Name'}
            ]
         }

 $('#ShowRecordsButton').click(function () {
           jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',
            {url:"salepointprovider.php?SalePointId=" + argSalePointId, page:1});
           jQuery("#grid").trigger('reloadGrid');
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

My grid without url send requests to server:

.../?_search=false&nd=1370817124473&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc

Set datatype: "local" solve problem.
Reload grid by

```
`function reloadGrid(gridId, gridData){
    $(gridId).jqGrid('clearGridData');  // need for nonempty grig (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/triggerreloadgrid-not-work/)
    $(gridId).jqGrid('setGridParam', {data: gridData}).trigger('reloadGrid');
}
`
```

No need to change datatype (at least for my json case it is recognized)

Answer (score 0):

In treegrid you couldn't use datatype = 'local'. So instead 'local', I set datatype = 'jsonstring', define empty fake data and jsonReader. jsonReader should be defined correctly according to your retrieved data. Thanks for Oleg's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6789333/4373947). And, when I need to load data, I simply change datatype to 'json'.

```
var fakeData ={
    rows: []
};
...
datatype: 'jsonstring',
datastr: fakeData,
...
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    root: function (obj) { return obj.rows; },
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

Comment: This is not answer to question.