# Is there a way to prevent jqGrid from autoloading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid and I don't want the grid to autoload.

I only want the grid to load once a user enters filter criteria.

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the same question as I [answerd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3271390/how-to-disable-autoload-in-jqgrid/3292602#3292602) before. You can define jqGrid with `datatype:'local'` parameter and after the user set filter criteria you can change it ot `datatype:'json'` with respect of

```
jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'});
```

By the way you can send the filter criterias to the server with respect of `postData` parameter of jqGrid. See [How to filter the jqGrid data NOT using the built in search/filter box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819) for details.