# jqGrid tree grid with local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

[jqGrid docs](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid) for tree grid says:

> "Currently jqGrid can work only with data returned from server. There are some tricks and articles which describes how to work with local data."

Fair enough, but I was unable to find such articles. Any hints on how I can achieve it, preferably with equivalent of `datatype=local`?

Comment: If you read my answer before look at the modified answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5322608/jqgrid-tree-view-adjacencey/5333199#5333199) old answer could help you. The demo which used the last current version of jqGrid you can find [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree2.htm).

**UPDATED**: Now I would be prefer to use `datatype: "jsonstring"` which is almost the same as `datatype: "local"`. One need to use `datastr: mydata` instead of `data: mydata` in the case. Additionally one have to use [jsonReader as function](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function). As the result one will have the following [modified demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTree3.htm).

The corresponding code of the demo you find below

```
var mydata = [
    { id:"1", name:"Cash",   num:"100", debit:"400.00",credit:"250.00", balance:"150.00", enbl:"1",
      level:"0", parent:"",  isLeaf:false, expanded:false, loaded:true },
    { id:"2", name:"Cash 1", num:"1",   debit:"300.00",credit:"200.00", balance:"100.00", enbl:"0",
      level:"1", parent:"1", isLeaf:false, expanded:false, loaded:true },
    { id:"3", name:"Sub Cash 1", num:"1",debit:"300.00",credit:"200.00", balance:"100.00", enbl:"1",
      level:"2", parent:"2", isLeaf:true,  expanded:false, loaded:true },
    { id:"4", name:"Cash 2", num:"2",debit:"100.00",credit:"50.00", balance:"50.00", enbl:"0",
      level:"1", parent:"1", isLeaf:true,  expanded:false, loaded:true },
    { id:"5", name:"Bank\'s", num:"200",debit:"1500.00",credit:"1000.00", balance:"500.00", enbl:"1",
      level:"0", parent:"",  isLeaf:false, expanded:true, loaded:true },
    { id:"6", name:"Bank 1", num:"1",debit:"500.00",credit:"0.00", balance:"500.00", enbl:"0",
      level:"1", parent:"5", isLeaf:true,  expanded:false, loaded:true },
    { id:"7", name:"Bank 2", num:"2",debit:"1000.00",credit:"1000.00", balance:"0.00", enbl:"1",
      level:"1", parent:"5", isLeaf:true,  expanded:false, loaded:true },
    { id:"8", name:"Fixed asset", num:"300",debit:"0.00",credit:"1000.00", balance:"-1000.00", enbl:"0",
      level:"0", parent:"",  isLeaf:true,  expanded:false, loaded:true }
    ],
    grid = $("#treegrid");

grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "jsonstring",
    datastr: mydata,
    colNames:["Id","Account","Acc Num","Debit","Credit","Balance","Enabled"],
    colModel:[
        {name:'id', index:'id', width:1, hidden:true, key:true},
        {name:'name', index:'name', width:180},
        {name:'num', index:'acc_num', width:80, align:"center"},
        {name:'debit', index:'debit', width:80, align:"right"},
        {name:'credit', index:'credit', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'balance', index:'balance', width:80,align:"right"},
        {name:'enbl', index:'enbl', width: 60, align:'center',
         formatter:'checkbox', editoptions:{value:'1:0'},
         formatoptions:{disabled:false}}
    ],
    height: 'auto',
    gridview: true,
    rowNum: 10000,
    sortname: 'id',
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    treedatatype: "local",
    ExpandColumn: 'name',
    caption: "Demonstrate how to use Tree Grid for the Adjacency Set Model",
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
    }
});
```

**UPDATED 2**: One should use `parent:"null"` or `parent:null` instead of `parent:""`.

Comment: I have TreeGrid working with local data as the example you have linked. The only problem i have is that local search is not working at all. Any ideas?

Comment: I have TreeGrid working with local data as shown here. The only problem i have is that local search is not working at all. Any ideas? If i disable treegrid, search is working properly as expected.

Comment: @nvrs: You are right the treegrid can't be filtered because of the [return](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.1.2/js/grid.base.js#L1418).

Comment: @Oleg What is the "loaded" field in mydata array for?

Comment: @hello_amigo: It's better that you ask new question about that and I post my answer with description. Only in the way other people could find the information on the stackoverflow. Probably other people have an interest in the same question?

Comment: @Oleg done. Here is a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27387267/877035). Thanks in advance.