# Load local JSON data in jQgrid without AddJsonRows

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using the method addJsonRows to add local data to a jQgrid. As this method disables the sorting I need another solution. One restriction: I can't set the url and fetch the data from the server because the data was passed through another component.

Underneath snippet enlightens the case. The commented line shows the restriction, I replaced it by defining a local variable to have a test case.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function loadPackageGrid() {
    // Get package grid data from hidden input.
    // var data = eval("("+$("#qsmId").find(".qsm-data-packages").first().val()+")");
        var data =  {
            "page": "1",
            "records": "2",
            "rows": [
                { "id": "83123a", "PackageCode": "83123a" },
                { "id": "83566a", "PackageCode": "83566a" }
            ]
        };

        $("#packages")[0].addJSONData(data);
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#packages").jqGrid({
            colModel: [
                { name: 'PackageCode', index: 'PackageCode', width: "110" },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: "300" }
            ],
            pager: $('#packagePager'),
            datatype: "local",
            rowNum: 10000,
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Packages",
            height: 150,
            pgbuttons: false,
            loadonce: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

I wonder how I could do this in an other (better) way to keep the sorting feature.
I tried something with the data option, without result.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I suppose that the same question is interesting for other persons. So +1 from me for the question.

You can solve the problem in at least two ways. The first one you can use [datatype: "jsonstring"](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_string) and `datastr: data`. In the case you need to add additional parameter `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }`.

The second way is to use `datatype: "local"` and `data: data.rows`. In the case the [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data) will be used to read the data from the `data.rows` array. The default `localReader` can read the data.

The corresponding demos are [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddJsonData.htm) and [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddJsonData1.htm).

I modified a little your data: filled "Name" column and included the third item in the input data.

Now you can use local paging, sorting and filtering/searching of the data. I included a little more code to demonstrate the features. Below you find the code of one from the demos:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    'use strict';
    var data = {
            "page": "1",
            "records": "3",
            "rows": [
                { "id": "83123a", Name: "Name 1", "PackageCode": "83123a" },
                { "id": "83432a", Name: "Name 3", "PackageCode": "83432a" },
                { "id": "83566a", Name: "Name 2", "PackageCode": "83566a" }
            ]
        },
        grid = $("#packages");

    grid.jqGrid({
        colModel: [
            { name: 'PackageCode', index: 'PackageCode', width: "110" },
            { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: "300" }
        ],
        pager: '#packagePager',
        datatype: "jsonstring",
        datastr: data,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
        rowNum: 2,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "Packages",
        height: "auto",
        ignoreCase: true
    });
    grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#packagePager',
        { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {},
        { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true });
    grid.jqGrid('filterToolbar', { defaultSearch: 'cn', stringResult: true });
});
```

**UPDATED**: I decided to add more details about the differences between `datatype: "jsonstring"` and `datatype: "local"` scenarios because the old answer be read and voted by many readers.

I suggest to modify the above code a little to show better the differences. The fist code uses `datatype: "jsonstring"`

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var data = [
            { id: "10", Name: "Name 1", PackageCode: "83123a", other: "x", subobject: { x: "a", y: "b", z: [1, 2, 3]} },
            { id: "20", Name: "Name 3", PackageCode: "83432a", other: "y", subobject: { x: "c", y: "d", z: [4, 5, 6]} },
            { id: "30", Name: "Name 2", PackageCode: "83566a", other: "z", subobject: { x: "e", y: "f", z: [7, 8, 9]} }
        ],
        $grid = $("#packages");

    $grid.jqGrid({
        data: data,
        datatype: "local",
        colModel: [
            { name: "PackageCode", width: 110 },
            { name: "Name", width: 300 }
        ],
        pager: "#packagePager",
        rowNum: 2,
        rowList: [1, 2, 10],
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        caption: "Packages",
        height: "auto",
        sortname: "Name",
        autoencode: true,
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
            var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid), str = "", p;
            for (p in rowData) {
                if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    str += "propery \"" + p + "\" + have the value \"" + rowData[p] + "\n";
                }
            }
            alert("all properties of selected row having id=\"" + rowid + "\":\n\n" + str);
        }
    });
    $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#packagePager",
        { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {},
        { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true });
    $grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn", stringResult: true });
});
```

It displays (see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddJsonData_.htm))

[image]

One can see **unsorted** items in the same order like input data. The items of input data will be saved in internal parameters `data` and `_index`. `getLocalRow` method used in `onSelectRow` shows that items of internal `data` contains only properties of input items which names corresponds to `name` property of some jqGrid columns. Additionally unneeded `_id_` property will be added.

On the other side [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AddJsonData1_.htm) which uses `datatype: "local"` displays **sorted** data and all properties inclusive complex objects will be still saved in the internal `data`:

[image]

The code used in the last demo is included below:

```js
$(function () {
    "use strict";
    var data = [
            { id: "10", Name: "Name 1", PackageCode: "83123a", other: "x", subobject: { x: "a", y: "b", z: [1, 2, 3]} },
            { id: "20", Name: "Name 3", PackageCode: "83432a", other: "y", subobject: { x: "c", y: "d", z: [4, 5, 6]} },
            { id: "30", Name: "Name 2", PackageCode: "83566a", other: "z", subobject: { x: "e", y: "f", z: [7, 8, 9]} }
        ],
        $grid = $("#packages");

    $grid.jqGrid({
        data: data,
        datatype: "local",
        colModel: [
            { name: "PackageCode", width: 110 },
            { name: "Name", width: 300 }
        ],
        pager: "#packagePager",
        rowNum: 2,
        rowList: [1, 2, 10],
        viewrecords: true,
        rownumbers: true,
        caption: "Packages",
        height: "auto",
        sortname: "Name",
        autoencode: true,
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
            var rowData = $(this).jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid), str = "", p;
            for (p in rowData) {
                if (rowData.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                    str += "propery \"" + p + "\" + have the value \"" + rowData[p] + "\"\n";
                }
            }
            alert("all properties of selected row having id=\"" + rowid + "\":\n\n" + str);
        }
    });
    $grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#packagePager",
        { add: false, edit: false, del: false }, {}, {}, {},
        { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true });
    $grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", { defaultSearch: "cn", stringResult: true });
});
```

So I would recommend to use `datatype: "local"` instead of `datatype: "jsonstring"`. `datatype: "jsonstring"` could have some advantages only in some very specific scenarios.

Comment: Once again big thanks for the answer! I notice that the demolinks are identical. However I managed it without the second demo, maybe it's useful for someone else.

Comment: owesome answer, thanx to @Brecht for nice question.

Comment: hi, @Oleg, I have one problem in that I am retrieving data through json and adding to jqgrid. but want to search locally, is it possible?

Comment: @ankit5607san: I am not sure why you need the behavior. If I understand your problem correctly you can use `datatype: "json"` with `loadonce: true`. In the case you need load *all data* from the server at once and the `datatype` will be changed to `"local"` after the first loading from the server. All next paging ans sorting/filtering will be done locally. To be able to refresh the data in the grid you can reset the `datatype` inside if `beforeRefresh`: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3772720/315935).

Comment: @Oleg here we are having an alert on clicking a row. Can we have another jqgrid on top of it?

Comment: @shv22: Yes of cause. You can create Dialog (or div with position:absolute) with new grid or create Grid as Subgrid for example (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10178440/315935)).

Comment: @Oleg thank you for your quick response. So, I have to add another grid in onSelectRow of the first grid?

Comment: @shv22: You don't describe exactly which kind of information you need to display. Thus it's difficult to answer you on the question where you use "I have to". You *can use* grid as subgrid, which seems to me the best choice based on information, which you currently post. There are other options too (TreeGrid, data grouping and so on). In case of Subgrid jqGrid create the column with a button ("+" by default). If the user click on the button, the row under the clicked row will be created and `subGridRowExpanded` be callked. You are free to display *any information* in the row inclusive a grid.

Comment: @shv22: See pictures created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31567652/315935), [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SubGrid.htm), created for [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4115481/315935), [the demo](https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/615qovew/64/), created for [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39546742/315935)

Comment: @Oleg sorry for not being clear on my question. I want a tree jqGrid which on clicking on + will have another jqgrid like a modal window we have in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36342432/display-bootstrap-modal-dialog-on-top-of-child-popup-window just the difference is there window but I want table

Comment: @shv22: I repeat that you should *describe an example of the data, which you need to display*. Your last comment means, that *you shouldn't use TreeGrid*. The usage of TreeGrid means that you have hierarchy of items and all the child items have **the same properties** as the parent node (see carefully on the *columns* of every row of the TreeGrid [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5333199/315935) for example).

Comment: @Oleg, I have posted my question here...please look into it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481585/jqgrid-as-a-modal-window-on-top-of-another-jqgrid

Comment: @shv22: I still don't full understand what you want to do and why. I repeat that it would be better if you *more detailed describe the input data*, which you have and describe *why* you want to display modal dialog. The first look on the data from your question looks like you should better use 3-level data grouping with `"header"` as `groupSummaryPos` (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/grouping2-summaryTypeAsArray.htm)) or `jqPivot` (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/pivotGroupingTotalsHideSomeColumns.htm)). One should first choose the best way to display the data

Comment: @Oleg this is what it is needed in our project....we already have 3 level grouping on our base grid now the demand is to have another jqgrid on top of it as an another modal window which will appear by clicking on the root node

Comment: @shv22: It's unclear many details: Which `datatype` you have? Where you have the data, which you need to display in the new grid? Which version of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which fork of jqGrid. Moreover I still not understand where you have some Implementation problems. Do you use jQuery UI or Bootstrap? Do you have static or dynamic div, which you use for the Dialog? Has the dialog ein `<table>`? Why you not just call `.jqGrid` on the table during opening the dialog? Where you have some problems?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127608/discussion-between-shv22-and-oleg).

Answer (score -1):

Great advice, Oleg.

In my web app, I pre-loaded some JSON data which looked like this:

```
    {
       WorkflowRuns: 
       [
           {
              WorkflowRunID: 1000,
              WorkflowRunName: "First record",
           },
           {
              WorkflowRunID: 1001,
              WorkflowRunName: "Second record",
           }
       ],
       UserInformation: 
       {
          Forename: "Mike",
          Surname: "Gledhill"
       }
}
```

And here's the code I needed to create the jqGrid, just based on the `WorkflowRuns` part of this JSON:

```
var JSONstring = '{ WorkflowRuns: [ { WorkflowRunID: 1000, .. etc .. } ]';

$("#tblWorkflowRuns").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: JSONstring.WorkflowRuns,
    localReader: {  
        id: "WorkflowRunID",
        repeatitems: false
    },
    ...
});
```

This was a bit of trial and error though.

For example, jqGrid seemed to ignore `datastr: JSONstring` for me.

And notice how, with local data, I needed to use `localReader`, rather than `jsonReader`, otherwise it wouldn't set the row IDs properly.

Hope this helps.