# JSON.parse: unexpected character exception on jqgrid

Tags: json, jqgrid

I am getting a JSON.parse: unexpected character exception while I am trying to read a local JSON in my JQGrid.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var jsondata =  { 
      "totalpages": "1", 
      "currpage": "1",
      "totalrecords": "2",
      "invdata" : [
        {"name":"New York City", "country":"USA", "continent":"NorthAmerica"},
        {"name":"Paris", "country":"France", "continent":"Europe"}

      ]
    };

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#grid").jqGrid({ data: jsondata,
                    datatype: "json",
                    colNames: ["Name", "Country", "Continent"],
                    colModel: [{
                        name: 'name',
                        index: 'name',
                        editable: true, 
                    }, {
                        name: 'country',
                        index: 'country',
                        editable: true,
                    }, {
                        name: 'continent',
                        index: 'continent',
                        editable: true,
                    }],
                    pager: '#pager',
                    jsonReader : {
                        root:"invdata",
                        page: "currpage",
                        total: "totalpages",
                        records: "totalrecords",
                        repeatitems: false,
                        id: "0"
                     },
                    caption:"Dynamic hide/show column groups"
            }).navGrid("#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false});

    jQuery("#hc").click( function() { jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('hideCol',["continent"]); }); 
    jQuery("#sc").click( function() { jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('showCol',["continent"]); });


});



</script>
```

I have tried to lookup in the jqgrid Wiki but still unable to figure out what's wrong. Is there a problem with the jsonReader? I have checked related questions but it didn't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving "jsondata" as a parameter to "data" for the jqgrid, give **data : jsondata.invdata**

Comment: got the answer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831306/load-local-json-data-in-jqgrid-without-addjsonrows