# Error in loading the data in jqgrid

Tags: php, jquery, html, jqgrid

I am trying to load the output from a php script into jqgrid but i can see the table without data.

```
<div id='Results'>
<div id= 'abcd' style="display:block";>
<?php include("simple.php");?> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var data=  $('#abcd').text();
var data1= data.replace(/\"/ig,'\"');
var data1= data1.replace(/[\“\”\″]/ig,'\"');
jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid({
dataType: "json",
data:data1,
colNames:['snp_id','chr','start_pos','end_pos','class','refbase','variantbase'],
colModel:[
  {name:'snp_id',index:'snp_id', width:50},
  {name:'chr',index:'chr', width:50},
  {name:'start_pos',index:'start_pos', width:60},
  {name:'end_pos',index:'end_pos', width:75},
  {name:'class',index:'class', width:75, align:"right" },
  {name:'refbase',index:'refbase', width:75},
  {name:'variantbase',index:'variantbase', width:150}
],
pager: '#pager',
rowNum:100,
sortname: 'snp_id',
sortorder: "asc",
viewrecords: true,
gridview: true,
height: '100%',
width: '100%',
caption:"Title",
loadComplete: function(reload) {
  jQuery("#myGridID").trigger("reloadGrid");
}
});
});
</script>
```

Simple.php retrieve the data in JSON format ito the div named 'abcd'

```
{"total":1,"page":1,"records":5,"rows":[{"id":"CaSNP000002","cell":[{"snp_id":"CaSNP000002","chr":"Ca4","start_pos":"10077235","end_pos":"10077254","class":"D","refbase":"CTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCT","variantbase":null}]},{"id":"CaSNP000003","cell":[{"snp_id":"CaSNP000003","chr":"Ca4","start_pos":"10077245","end_pos":"10077254","class":"D","refbase":"CTCTCTCTCT","variantbase":null}]},{"id":"CaSNP000004","cell":[{"snp_id":"CaSNP000004","chr":"Ca4","start_pos":"10077253","end_pos":"10077254","class":"D","refbase":"CT","variantbase":null}]},{"id":"CaSNP000005","cell":[{"snp_id":"CaSNP000005","chr":"Ca4","start_pos":"10077254","end_pos":"10077255","class":"I","refbase":"------                                                                                              ","variantbase":"CTCTCT"}]},{"id":"CaSNP000006","cell":[{"snp_id":"CaSNP000006","chr":"Ca4","start_pos":"10077254","end_pos":"10077255","class":"I","refbase":"--------                                                                                            ","variantbase":"CTCTCTCT"}]}]}
```

Comment: i didnt seen any errors but table is empty

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code ... I am not 100% it will work :)

P.S> Updated.. If its not working try to debug your problem.. search for errors use console logs etc.. Without error its not easy to find your problem

```
<div id= 'abcd' style="display:block";>
<?php include("simple.php");?> 
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
var data= $('#abcd').text();
data = jQuery.trim(data); // to remove all empty spaces else json parse may fail
data = jQuery.parseJson(data); // parsing string to json object/array
jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:['snp_id','chr','start_pos','end_pos','class','refbase','variantbase'],
    colModel:[
      {name:'snp_id',index:'snp_id', width:50},
      {name:'chr',index:'chr', width:50},
      {name:'start_pos',index:'start_pos', width:60},
      {name:'end_pos',index:'end_pos', width:75},
      {name:'class',index:'class', width:75, align:"right" },
      {name:'refbase',index:'refbase', width:75},
      {name:'variantbase',index:'variantbase', width:150}
    ],
    pager: '#pager',
    rowNum: data.rows.length,
    sortname: 'snp_id',
    sortorder: "asc",
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    caption:"Title",
    loadComplete: function(reload) {
      jQuery("#myGridID").trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
});
var mydata = data.rows;
for(var i=0;i<=mydata.length;i++)
    jQuery("#tableid").jqGrid('addRowData',i+1,mydata[i]);
});
</script>
```

Comment: No changes. . . still its same

Comment: Try to add console.log(data); at start of your javascript after the var data = line to see if its parsing correctly JSON ..

Comment: ya its parsing correctly. i can see data in json format in firebug console. "Object { total=1, page=1, records=11, more...}"

Answer (score 0):

I did some demoing based on your snippet, using datatype like this:

```
            datatype: 'jsonstring',
            datastr:data,
```

finally populated the grid for me. I found the solution from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833082/1945020

Comment: It creates blank rows. still data is not loading

Comment: Difference propably was, that I stripped out the PHP-part allthogether. I just added a JSONLint-validated json string to the div and read it to data-variable. Maybe you could try to isolate the problem by pasting the output of your PHP to the div, read it from there and see if that works.