# TypeError: undefined is not a function in jqGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I am working on jqGrid. I am new to it. I am using data type as 'local'. whenever I used to execute the line jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({...}), I get an error as 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' No other information i am getting with this. The code is as below:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jqModal.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/jqDnR.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/grid.formedit.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/JQGrid/grid.common.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<table id="list2"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
var mydata = [
    { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" },
    { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00" },
    { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00" },
    { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00" }
    ];


    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: mydata,
        colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
            { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
            { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
            { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 150, sortable: false }
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
        //pager: '#pager2',
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "JSON Example"
    });

    for (var i = 0; i <= _data.length; i++)
        jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('addRowData', i + 1, mydata[i]);
});
```

The code above is taken from [jqGrid official website](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Where am going wrong?
also, Which datatype should I use local or json and why? I didn't find better and easy to understand description anywhere.

Comment: Are the links to your scripts and stylesheet being resolved? If you're using razor v1 they should be wrapped in `@Url.Content("~/Scripts....")`?

Comment: Give a look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831306/load-local-json-data-in-jqgrid-without-addjsonrows

Comment: Upvote, valid question

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : I tried wrapping scripts and styleshieets in @Url.Content("~/Scripts...."). But still same issue

Comment: @TheGr8_Nik : I went through the link and and also tried it. But same problem.