# "undefined is not a function" in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

In JQgrid for delete operation, I'm using this deldata to send the key value to the server.

```
               delData: {
                dnis: function () {
                    var sel_id = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    var value = $('#jQGridDemo').jqGrid('getCell', sel_id, 'DNIS');
                    return value;
                }
```

In the same way, to reload the grid after add, I'm using this nippet.

```
              afterSubmit: function (response, postdata) {
                $("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                return [false, response.responseText]
                },
```

But everywhere on using `$("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid(` i get this following error

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

I spent my full day, but couldn't find the reason of the problem.

I'm using this grid in MVC cshtml razor view.

This is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23779247/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-in-jqgrid) question. Please help me out.

Comment: Did you include the jqGrid JS file?

Comment: @EvanDarwin yes, I did.. JQGrid is loading. I could able to get and post data.