# jqGrid Table is Empty

Tags: jqgrid

This is my table generation codefor jqGrid 3.5.2

```
var jsonData = [{"KEY.ServiceId":"Service ID","KEY.ServiceDefinition":"Service Definition","KEY.Upload":"Upload","KEY.Download":"Download"}];
$('#' + id + 'Grid').jqGrid({
    datatype: 'json',                   
    rows : jsonData ,                   
    colNames: [ 'KEY.ServiceId',
                'KEY.ServiceDefinition',
                'KEY.Upload ',
                'KEY.Download'
    ],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'KEY.ServiceId', index: 'KEY.ServiceId', width: 135, sortable: false },
        { name: 'KEY.ServiceDefinition', index: 'KEY.ServiceDefinition', width: 175, sortable: false },     
        { name: 'KEY.Upload', index: 'KEY.Upload', width: 110, sortable: false },
        { name: 'KEY.Download', index: 'KEY.Download', width: 110, sortable: false }
    ],
    height:         '100',  
    scrollOffset:   0,
    loadComplete:   function(loadData) {                        
        if (loadData == null || loadData.rows == null || loadData.rows.length == null || loadData.rows.length <= 5) {                           
            $('#' + id + 'Grid').setGridHeight("auto");
        }
    },
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false
    },
    loadui:         'disable',
    altRows:        true,
    viewrecords:    true,
    loadonce:       true,
    caption:        'My Caption'
});
```

However when I run it I do not get any error and table is empty.

**EDIT:** I have fixed my code and created a working fiddle example at here: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/9668/ However it does not work with jqGrid 3.5.2?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `datatype: 'local'` if you use local json object. And not `rows`, but `data: jsonData`.

Here is a great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833082/1849444) that mension other ways of solving your problem provided by Oleg.

Comment: I tried what you said and here is a fiddle works for one of the latest versions of jqGrid: http://jsfiddle.net/yNw3C/9668/ However it does not work for jqGrid 3.5.2 Do you have any solution for it?