# jqgrid: subgrid toolbar does not display

Tags: jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 4.8.2. I'm trying to follow along with the examples on the demo site.  I've created a parent grid and need to show a subgrid (as a grid).  For some reason, the toolbar pager for the subgrid won't display. The rowNum, width and height options are working, though. I've looked at the demo and I can't see what I'm doing wrong. Would someone take a look at the following code, please?

```
var lastSelection;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'servlet/getData',
    datatype: "json",
    editurl: "servlet/updateProduct",
    page: 1, 
     colModel: [
        { label: 'ID', name: 'ProductId', width: 75, key: true },
        { label: 'Category', name: 'CategoryName', width: 90 },
        { label: 'Name', name: 'ProductName', width: 100 },
        { label: 'Country', name: 'Country', width: 80 },
        { label: 'Price', name: 'Price', width: 80 },
        { label: 'Qty', name: 'Quantity', width: 80 },
        { label: 'Included?', name: 'Included', width: 80,
                editable: true, 
                edittype: "checkbox", 
                editOptions: {value:"Yes:No"} }
    ],
    viewrecords: true, // show the current page, data range and total records on the toolbar
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        var grid = $('#jqGrid');
        if (rowid && rowid !== lastSelection) {
            grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
            lastSelection = rowid;
        }
        grid.jqGrid('editRow', lastSelection, {keys: true, 
            extraparam : {
                home: "livonia", 
                productName: function(){
                    var row = grid.getRowData(lastSelection);

                    // Both of these work:
                    var temp = row.ProductName;
                    var temp1 = row['ProductName'];

                    return row.ProductName;
                }
            }
        } 
        );

    },
    width: 780,
    height: 200,
    rowNum: 10,
    pager: "#jqGridPager",

    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var lastSubgridSelection;

        var grid = $('#jqGrid');
        var row = grid.getRowData(row_id);  
        var productId = row.ProductId;

           var subgrid_table_id;
           subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_t";
           jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table>");
           jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
              url: 'servlet/getProductWarehouses?q=2&id=' + row_id + '&productId=' + productId,
              datatype: "json",
                page: 1, 
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Product ID', name: 'ProductId', width: 75, key: false, hidden: true },
                    { label: 'Whse ID', name: 'WhseId', width: 90, key: true },
                    { label: 'Whse Name', name: 'WhseName', width: 90 },
                    { label: 'Qty', name: 'Quantity', width: 80 },
                    { label: 'Included?', name: 'Included', width: 80,
                    editable: true, 
                    edittype: "checkbox", 
                    editOptions: {value:"Yes:No"} }
                ],
            viewrecords: true,
            height: '100%',
            width: 400,
            rowNum: 5,
            pager: "#jqGridPager" + "_" + subgrid_id
           });
       }

});


});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean probably that **the pager** (not the toolbar) will be not displayed in subgrids.

The reason is very easy if you understand how the [grid as subgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:subgrid_as_grid) feature works in jqGrid. If you just add `subGrid: true` to the grid (to the main grid) then jqGrid insert additional column in `colModel` with the name `"subgrid"`. The column will have `+` icons which can be used to "expand" subgrid. If the user clicks on the `+` icon then the new row will be added under the row with `+` icon. The row will contains `<td>` with the icon and `<td>` with span over the whole grid. The last `<td>` will contains the subdrid. Before call of `subGridRowExpanded` jqGrid creates empty `<div>` in the cell with id constructed from grid id, "_" and rowid (of expanding row). The first parameter of `subGridRowExpanded` callback (`subgrid_id` in your code) contains the id of the empty `<div>`. The picture below shows the described above

[image]

I marked in red color the subgrid row. The id of empty div is `jqGrid_10` in the above example because the rowid is `10` and the grid id is `jqGrid`.

It's important to understand that you have to create `<table>` element for subgrid dynamically inside of `subGridRowExpanded` callback. If you want that the subgrid have the pager then you have to create `<div>` for the pager too. **The problem in your code: you just use `pager: "#jqGridPager" + "_" + subgrid_id` option for subgrid, but you don't created `<div>` with the corresponding id.**

The next problem: every row (`<tr>`) of subgrid will have `id` attribute (rowid). So one have to assign it. The user can open multiple subgrids at the same time. **The problem is that it's possible to have id duplicates because of usage the same `id` in two different subgrids or between subgrid and the main grid.** To fix the problem with id conflicts it's strictly recommended to use `idPrefix` parameter for subgrid with the value which is different for every subgrid.

A possible fixed implementation of `subGridRowExpanded` could be the following:

```js
subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowid) {
    var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
        subgridPagerId = subgridDivId + "_p";
    $("#" + subgridDivId)
        .append($subgrid)
        .append("<div id='" +subgridPagerId + "'></div>");

    $subgrid.jqGrid({
        url: 'servlet/getProductWarehouses',
        postData: {
            q: 2,
            id: rowid,
            productId: rowid
        },
        datatype: "local",
        colModel: [
            { label: 'Product ID', name: 'ProductId', width: 75, hidden: true },
            { label: 'Whse ID', name: 'WhseId', width: 90, key: true },
            { label: 'Whse Name', name: 'WhseName', width: 90 },
            { label: 'Qty', name: 'Quantity', width: 80 },
            { label: 'Included?', name: 'Included', width: 80,
                editable: true,
                edittype: "checkbox",
                editOptions: {value:"Yes:No"} }
        ],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: '100%',
        width: 400,
        rowNum: 5,
        //idPrefix: subgridDivId + "_",
        idPrefix: rowid + "_",
        pager: "#" + subgridPagerId
    });
}
```

By the way you use `key: true` property for the column `ProductId` of the main grid. So the rowid of the main grid will be the same as the `ProductId`. Because of that I used `productId: rowid` in the above code. One more remark. I used `idPrefix: rowid + "_"` for subgrid. One can use successfully other values in the same way, for example `idPrefix: subgridDivId + "_"`.