# Display bootstrap modal dialog on top of child popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm modifying Moodle LMS to include some user alerts during their chat sessions if some problems have been identified. Chat module in Moodle appears as a popup window displayed on top of Moodle index page.

Since I can't modify Moodle core code, I'm able to embed some custom javascript code in the Moodle index page, but not in the chat child popup window. This custom javascript code displays bootstrap Modal dialog with notification for the user, but the problem is that this modal dialog is covered by the child popup, so user doesn't see the message.

Ideal scenario would be if modal dialog appears on top of child popup window. However, if that's not possible another solution might be if somehow I can return focus to parent window so user is still able to see notification in modal dialog before he returns to the chat window.

I hope someone has some idea how to make this work.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing `z-index`es?

Comment: Yes. That was the first thing I tried. I've set style="z-index=99999" on modal-dialog.

Comment: What does the html for the chat window look like? Have you looked at the styles associated with the chat window?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. After looking more carefully in the child popup I realized that all the javascript files from parent page are injected to the child page. That makes it possible to create custom functions that will run on the child page and provide a notification inside the page.