# Learning jqGrid without database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid and I want to learn it. So, my first question is can we use it without database and php by only using HTML and Javascript. I want to implement a tree node click event in the jqGrid. So, can I create virtual columns in without using database and php and on click event can I define to have another jqGrid on top of it.

It would be like having an alert box when clicking but this time I want to have to another jqGrid on top of it. It is possible without using database and php.

Comment: yes you can use that but for that you need to create a json file as data source of jqgrid

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831306/load-local-json-data-in-jqgrid-without-addjsonrows