# jqGrid autoencode=true not used when addJSONData is called

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

If I return JSON that contains javascript from server and populate it to jqGrid via addJSONData it will be executed even I have autoencode = true in options. To prevent XSS I had to modify jqGrid´s addCell function this way

```
        var v,prp;
        // This if block has been added
        if(ts.p.autoencode) {
            cell = $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cell);
        }
        v = formatter(rowId,cell,pos,srvr,'add');
        prp = formatCol( pos,irow, v, srvr, rowId, true);
        return "<td role=\"gridcell\" "+prp+">"+v+"</td>";
```

Is this the correct way to prevent XSS or is there some other way in jqGrid to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't understand how javascript can be inside of JSON and not HTML (see "I return JSON that contains javascript"). Could you describe your scenario for Cross-Site-Scripting attack more detailed or better provide the corresponding demo?

I personally don't understand why you use `addJSONData` at all. My one from the first posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660226/315935) on the stackoverflow was about the subject. Nevertheless I think the data will be do encoded if you use `autoencode: true` option. If you look at the code of `addJSONData` you will find [the line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L1331)

```
rowData.push( addCell(idr,v,j+gi+si+ni,i+rcnt,cur) );
```

which use `addCell` to add the cell content to the grid. The internal function [addCell](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L995-1000) calls [formatter](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L979-994) which calls [cellVal](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.3.1/js/grid.base.js#L976-978) per default

```
v = cellVal(cellval);
```

and the `cellVal(val)` returns

```
$.jgrid.htmlEncode(val)
```

for any non-empty `val` in case of `autoencode: true`.

If you do see some problem or some bug in the code you should better to post the demo which can be used to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 0):

In our application user inputs are saved as is and returned to UI which responsibility is to encode it.

Here's example JSON data returned from server that contains javascript

```
{"page":1,"total":1,"records":1,"rows":[{"id":"1","cell":["10jcmjn30jjiej8l499p","NO_ALERTS:Ei hälytyksiä","<script>console.log('jep');</script>","Pentti P.","3.4.2012 15:47","Kaupunki","Teiden auraus, KLO","Muu, Moite, Kiitos","Käsittelyssä, Odottaa vastausta","Ei määritetty","Luottamuksellinen","-","0","Kirjattu","x"]}]}
```

I have used lots of time to make jqGrid work actually very well in our application (thanks for the great piece of software) and addJSONData has been used so I wouldn't change it without need to do it.

To the problem - in formatter

```
} else if($.fmatter){
```

is always called. In my javascript knowledge $.fmatter is always true so the last else won't ever be called. Actually it seems that the bug is in jqGrid's Formatter module not in base module.

$.fn.fmatter doesn't do any encoding. In my situation it never goes to

```
if ($.fn.fmatter[formatType]){
```

block but it always returns given cellval as is. Maybe that would be the right place to do encoding?

This is what I did to make this work in our application

```
$.fn.fmatter = function(formatType, cellval, opts, rwd, act) {
        // build main options before element iteration
        var v=cellval;
        opts = $.extend({}, $.jgrid.formatter, opts);

        if ($.fn.fmatter[formatType]){
            v = $.fn.fmatter[formatType](cellval, opts, rwd, act);
        } else {
            v = $.jgrid.htmlEncode(cellval);
        }

        return v;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found there is a XSS flaw (at least in jqGrid 4.5.4, maybe newer versions?) due to the row's `id` attribute being set by data returned from an AJAX call not being [appropriately cleaned (as per OWASP XSS rule 2)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes). The problem comes from `constructTr` not sanitizing the `id` parameter*, which then goes into `rowData` which gets appended to a DOM element in the `addJSONData` function.

Unfortunately `constructTr` cannot be easily patched due to its scope, but you can patch the `getAccessor` function which typically feeds the id to `constructTr`.

```
(function(jgrid){
    var _getAccessor = jgrid.getAccessor;
    function htmlAttributeEncode (value) {
        /* your encoding function here */
        return encodedValue;
    }
    jgrid.getAccessor = function () {
        return htmlAttributeEncode(_getAccessor.apply(jgrid, arguments));
    };
})(jQuery.jgrid);
```

(Haven't tested that exact solution, but something like that should work.)

* *Note:* Other attributes are also not cleaned, but I'm not sure if they can contain raw data from the AJAX call. Worth investigating more.