# jqGrid has no addJSONData method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqgrid

I'm just playing around with jqGrid this afternoon, and have it working fairly well with a local array data source.  However, now I'm trying to get it to load local JSON data.

My code is as follows:

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
   datatype: "json", //<-- Also tried "local" here
   height: 'auto',
   autowidth: true,
   forceFit: true,
   colNames:['ID','Name'],
   colModel:[
      {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", jsonmap:"id"},
      {name:'name',index:'name', width:90, jsonmap: "name"}
   ],
   multiselect: false,
   caption: "Test"
});
```

I then try to load JSON data using the following:

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid.addJSONData(json);
```

The issue is that `jQuery("#list4").jqGrid.addJSONData` is undefined.  I've also tried:

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid('addJSONData', json);
```

Which throws an exception saying that the method `addJSONData` is not defined.  I can see other documented methods on `jQuery("#list4").jqGrid`, just not this one.  `addXMLData` is also missing.  However, I can verify that these methods are in the `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` source code.

I just downloaded jqGrid today, so I know I have the latest versions of everything.

I must be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it could be.  I've put the *entire* page here:

http://pastie.org/3825067

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `addJSONData` is very old method which uses still expandos to the DOM element of the grid (`<table>` element). So to use `addJSONData` correctly one should use

```
jQuery("#list4")[0].addJSONData(json);
```

See [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods). More beter way will be **to create jqGrid and fill the data directly**. You can use

```
jQuery("#list4").jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: mydata,
    height: 'auto',
    autowidth: true,
    colNames: ['ID', 'Name'],
    colModel: [
        {name: 'id', index: 'id', width: 60, sorttype: "int", key: true},
        {name: 'name', index:'name', width: 90}
    ],
    caption: "Test",
    gridview: true // !!! improve the performance
});
```

The format of `mydata` can be like

```
var mydata = [
        {id: 10, name: "Oleg"},
        {id: 20, name: "Mike"}
    ];
```

It's allow to use local paging, filtering and sorting of data. The input data need *not* be sorted.

Alternatively you can use `datatype: 'jsonstring'` and `datastr`. The value of `datastr` can be either JSON string or already parsed object. The data from `datastr` *have to be correctly sorted* (if you use some `sortname` and `sortorder` parameters) and have the same format as for `datatype: 'json'` (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data)). One can use `jsonReader` and `jsonmap` to specify the data format:

```
var mydata = {
        //total: 1,  // will be ignored
        //page: 1,   // will be ignored
        //records: 2 // will be ignored
        rows: [
            {id: 10, name: "Oleg"},
            {id: 20, name: "Mike"}
        ]
    ];
```

What is the most strange for me is *why* you need to load "local JSON data"? Where is the difference to the "local array data source"? You can use [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to convert the input data to object or use `datatype: 'jsonstring'` directly. In the most cases the usage of `addJSONData` is because of **loading the data from the server manually per jQuery.ajax** which is really bed idea (see one from my first posts on the stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660226/315935)). jqGrid has a lot of customization options and callbackes like `ajaxGridOptions`, `serializeGridData` and `beforeProcessing`, you can use functions in `jsonReader` (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function)) and `jsonmap`, which allows you to load practically *any* format of input data. Using [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options), `serializeGridData` and `postData` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935)) you can make practically any customization of the parameters sent to the server. So the usage of low-level `addJSONData` are needed really in extremely very seldom scenarios.

Comment: Hi - The problem is I don't have the data when the page loads.  A user clicks a button to load the data depending on their search criteria.  When the user clicks the button, I need to clear out any existing data in the grid and load new data.  `AddJSONData` was the only thing I found that would do that, everything else wanted me to pass in a datasource to the grid initializer..

Comment: @MikeChristensen: If you need don't load the grid at the page loading you can start with `datatype: 'local'`. Then if the user set some criteria and click on "Search"  button you can change the datatype to `'json'` using `setGridParam` and reload the grid. Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5398136/315935) for more details. jqGrid clear previous data (existing data) in the grid automatically.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much!  This is enough info to get the ball rolling..  On Monday anyway..  Right now I don't care about grids..

Answer (score 6):

For the most part, you are close.  I don't think the addJSONData method is the way to go. Here's how we deal with local JSON data:

The grid:

```
$("#list4").jqGrid({
   datatype: "local", //<-- "local" tells jqGrid not to try and get the data itself
   height: 'auto',
   autowidth: true,
   forceFit: true,
   colNames:['ID','Name'],
   colModel:[
      {name:'id',index:'id', width:60, sorttype:"int", jsonmap:"id"},
      {name:'name',index:'name', width:90, jsonmap: "name"}
   ],
   multiselect: false,
   caption: "Test"
});
```

Give data to the grid:

```
// Clear the grid if you only want the new data
$('#list4').clearGridData(true); 
// Set the data the tell the grid to refresh
$('#list4').setGridParam({ data: jsonData, rowNum: jsonData.length }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

You should also change your jsonData to:

```
var jsonData = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Apple'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Banana'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Pear'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Orange'}
];
```

jqGrid is going to look to match up the columns specified to the objects passed into the array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working with version jqGrid 4.1.2 
Having initialized the grid with a JSONReader and `datatype:'jsonstring'`, when adding jsonstring data I've to include the `datatype:'jsonstring'` parameter.

```
$('#list4').setGridParam({ datastr: jsonData, datatype:'jsonstring', rowNum: jsonData.length }).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

As far as I know that is because after initialize the datatype:'jsonstring' is turned to datatype:'local', so when adding jsonstring it tries to load data from "data" param instead of "datastr" but because is empty no data is loaded.

I hope to contribute to this ...