# JQgrid addJSONData is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms, jqgrid

I have the following problem when trying to add the data returned in addJSONData of Jqgrid I get the message **grid.addJSONData is not a function**

this is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb"   MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="Asignación_Tickets.aspx.vb" Inherits="Wisetrack.Project.WebApp.Asignación_Tickets" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Manifiestos Detalle
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
    <link href="Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link type="text/css" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="Scripts/jqGrid/grid.locale-es.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>--%>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.js"></script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            //'use strict';

            jQuery("#txtDateIni").datetimepicker({
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                timepicker: false,
                //formatTime: 'H:i',
                formatDate: 'd/m/Y',
                startDate: true,
                //step:1, //subir minuto
                yearStart: 1950,
            });
            jQuery("#txtDateFin").datetimepicker({
                format: 'd/m/Y',
                timepicker: false,
                //formatTime: 'H:i',
                formatDate: 'd/m/Y',
                startDate: true,
                //step: 1, //subir minuto
                yearStart: 1950,
            });

            jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('es');


            var dtmInicio = $("#txtDateIni").val();
            var dtmFin = $("#txtDateFin").val();

            getProgramacionByDate(dtmInicio, dtmFin);
        });

        function getProgramacionByDate(dtmInicio, dtmFin) {
            debugger;
            var params = new Object();
            params.dtmInicio = dtmInicio;
            params.dtmFin = dtmFin;

            $.jgrid.defaults.styleUI = 'Bootstrap';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "Asignación_Tickets.aspx/BuscarProgramacion",
                data: JSON.stringify(params),
                dataType: "json",
                //async: false,
                success: function (data, textStatus) {


                    if (textStatus == "success") {
                        debugger;
                        console.log(data);
                        $("#jqGridListProgramacion").clearGridData();

                        var grid = $("#jqGridListProgramacion")[0];

                        console.log(grid);

                        grid.addJSONData($.parseJSON(data.d));
                    }
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                    console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(request.responseText).Message);
                }
            });

        }
        function bntAcciones(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                return '<a style="text-align:center !important;font-size:15px;"  onClick=fn_cargarModalFormularioDetalleCobertura(' + rowObject.Id_programa + ');><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ver Detalle" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon-grid"></span></a>';
        };
        </script>
    <div class="GmdBody-header">
            <h2>Búsqueda Coberturas</h2>
    </div>
<div class="GmdBody-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fecha Inicio Cobertura</label>
                <div class='input-group date'>
                    <input type="text" id="txtDateIni" class="form-control" />
                    <%--<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control txtDateIni" ID="txtDateIni"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Fecha Fin Cobertura</label>
                <div class='input-group'>
                    <input type="text" id="txtDateFin" class="form-control" />
                    <%--<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="txtDateFin"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label style="visibility:hidden;">Fecha Inicio Cobertura</label>
                <div class="input-group list-inline">
                    <button class="btn btn-info " type="button" id="btnBuscar"  style="margin-right : 10px; padding-right: 30px;padding-left: 20px;background-color:#04788b"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="padding-right:5px;"></span>Buscar</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary " type="button" id="btnLimpiar" style="padding-right: 20px; padding-left: 20px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="padding-right:5px;"></span>Registrar</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <table id="jqGridListProgramacion"></table>
            <div id="jqGridPagerListProgramacion">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

the error message that returns me is this **grid.addJSONData is not a function**, 
I have consulted this error here without success : [jqGrid has no addJSONData method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253938/jqgrid-has-no-addjsondata-method), please help

Comment: I do not see the grid creation. Where is the grid created? Maybe you use methods which are apliied to the not existing jqGrid.

Comment: how can i initialize the jqgrid

Comment: Before to call any jqGrid method, the grid should be first created - see [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/#quick-start)

Comment: Thank you was what I needed