# jqgrid and jquery tabs : loading text doesn't hide

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

i am using jquery UI Tabs (1.8.9) and i have some tabs in my web page.

On each tab, i have a jqGrid 3.8.2 which is loading json data at the loading of the page.

For the first tab, everything is ok, i see the Loading yellow box from jqGrid and it disappears. But the problem is, when i move to another tab, i see the jqGrid loaded but i have the small loadui from JQGrid still appearing on all jqgrid of hidden tabs. Refreshing hides it ..

Is it a bug ? something i can fix ? or is there a way to hide it when i change tab ? (i have tried hiding $(".loading") when i change tab but it doesn't work ..

Hmmm one detail : it does that only in IE7 not in Firefox nor Chrome

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqGrid use up to two divs to show the loading processing. if `loadui` has default value `'enable'` one div with the id having prefix `load_` are used. If you use `loadui` rqual to `'block'` an additional overlay div with the id having prefix `lui_` are used.

For example if you use `<table>` with `id="list"` the ids of divs which will be used during data loading are `'load_list'` and additionally `'lui_list'` (if `loadui:'block'`). Additionally during the grid loading another grid parameter `$("#list")[0].grid.hDiv.loading` will be set to `true` during the grid loading.

So you can implement inside of [select](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-select) event handler of [jQuery UI tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) hiding and showing the loading divs. Additionally you can test `$("#grid_id")[0].grid.hDiv.loading` to verify that the grid is really in loading status.

You can read more about the loading dives used by jqGrid [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705719/jqgrid-trigger-loading-overlay/2706447#2706447).

Comment: excellent answer Oleg, you are the best :)  I have found that the $("#list") is hidden but it still shows in IE7, i don't know why. One trick is to make a $("#load_list").html("Loading in progress...") on tabs select event and they disappear .. not clean but it works

Comment: @Fredv: You are welcome! Vous êtes les bienvenus! One of possible reason of IE7 problems could be an old jQuery version which you use. I recommend you to use either 1.5.2 or 1.6.1. I suppose that there are an exception in IE7 during processing of JSON data. You can use and debugger to localize the problem. For example Visual Studio or [Developer Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) could help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does this is because in IE if the element is in a hidden element it won't hide it properly.  I'm not sure what all versions this affects but definitely 6 and 7.

Anyway the fix I have found is to make the jQuery UI tabs hide by moving offscreen, not by setting visibility to none.

This is done by changing the CSS for the ui-tabs-hide class.  Add the following to the CSS on the page that includes your tabs

```
.ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide  
{
    display: block !important; 
    position:absolute;
    left: -99999px;
    top: 0;
}
```

The first .ui-tabs can be changed to a more specific selector.

Anyway after the change the loading boxes should disappear as intended.