# jqgrid width size problem in usercontrol

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, user-controls, jqgrid

I have a `jqgrid` in the third tab of a jquery ui tab, the grid is visible but the size is much smaller than its usual size. I dont have this problem when I move the grid to the first tab. I read and know that the hidden tabs are not reflecting the width and have seen some similar issues like this one: [jqgrid and jquery tabs : loading text doesn't hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6303749/jqgrid-and-jquery-tabs-loading-text-doesnt-hide)

I would like to load my grid when the third tab is clicked in the `select` event of the tabs so the `jqgrid` is loaded with its original size.
This is my code in the usercontrol page that includes the tabs. I should also add that each tab has its own `.ascx` page (I dont know if this makes  a difference).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabstest").tabs({
        "select": function (event, ui) {
            switch (ui.index) {
            case 2:         
                alert(" this is the test cases ");
                $("#list")[0].grid.hDiv.reloadGrid;
                $("#list")[0].grid.reloadGrid;
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

---

```
<div id="tabstest">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">first</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Third </a></li>
    </ul>


    <div id="tabs-1">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("First", ViewData);  %>            
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-2">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("second");  %>            
    </div>

    <div id="tabs-3">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("Third");  %>            
    </div>


</div>
```

It is not loading my grid correctly, but the alert string shows so I am sure I enter this `select` event. Has anyone had this experience before? Any other tips will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you want achieve with the statements `$("#list")[0].grid.hDiv.reloadGrid` or `$("#list")[0].grid.reloadGrid`? To reload the grid you need do something like `$("#list").trigger("reloadGrid")`.

Comment: I was trying to reload the grid once the tab was clicked and it did not work I did try the $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid") but it did not work so finally I found   $("#tabstest").tabs( "load" , 2 ) and it loads when the tab is clicked, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer, I hope it helps

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$("#tabstest").tabs({ 
    "select": function (event, ui) { 
        switch (ui.index) { 
        case 2:          
           $("#tabstest").tabs( "load" , 2 )
            break; 
        } 
    } 
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what those methods in your case are trying to do exactly (as Oleg asked) but you could always just adjust the styles after the grid has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabstest").tabs({
        "select": function (event, ui) {
            switch (ui.index) {
            case 2:         
                $('#grid').css('width', '100%');  // Something like this
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```