# Manually trigger jqxGrid Loading Icon

Tags: jquery, loading, jqxgrid

I'm using jqxGrid and the Loading overlay only appears when the page is first loaded - not when sorting/filtering/paging.

This thread ([jqGrid trigger "Loading..." overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705719/jqgrid-trigger-loading-overlay)) had some good suggestions, but they didn't work. If anyone has some more up-to-date information I'd appreciate it.

I am familiar w/ the jQuery BlockUI plugin, but I'd prefer to do this directly in the grid if possible.

Comment: I received a response from the JQWidgets team, and apparently they've never had a loadui option for their system (linked thread). I've posted their response below.

Comment: We never had such API [loadui] in jqxGrid. I suppose that you’ve found something for a different Grid. We don’t have built-in API for forcing the Loading image to appear.

Best Regards,
Peter Stoev

jQWidgets Team

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be getting mixed up between JQGrid and JQXGrid