# Disable entire jqGrid

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have been looking for methods on how to disable a jqGrid and I found some:

1. Using BlockUI plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/block/
2. Using jqGrid options: loadui and set it to 'block'

First option is a great solution (I have not tried yet) and it is clearer maybe but I want to avoid using plugins if I can whenever I can do it by setting object properties so I am trying the second option but it is not working for me, jqGrid continues enabled.

My jqgrid in my asp.net mvc 4 view:

```
<div id="jqGrid">
    @Html.Partial("../Grids/_PartialGrid")
</div>
```

and _PartialGrid:

```
<table id="_compGrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
</table>
<div id="_compPager" style="text-align: center;">
</div>
```

so in the view, in script section I perform below on document ready and depending on the status of a property in my model (I disable it if id>0, otherwise I enable it on page reload):

```
@section scripts
{
    @Content.Script("/Grids/CompGrid.js", Url) // Content is a helper javascript loader (see end of this post)
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    showGrid();
    var disableCompGrid = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ItemCompViewModel));
    setStatusCompGrid(disableCompGrid.id > 0);

}
</script>
```

CompGrid.js is:

```
function showGrid() {
    $('#_compGrid').jqGrid({
        caption: paramFromView.Caption,
        colNames: ....
}

function setStatusCompGrid(disabled) {
           $('#_compGrid').jqGrid({
                loadui: 'block',
                loadtext: 'Processing...'
           });
}
```

In the code above, also I have tried to pass as parameter disabled to showGrid function and depending on if it is true or false to set a variable to 'block' or 'enable' respectively and then setting loadui property with this variable but it is not working.

Content.cshtml:

```
@using System.Web.Mvc;

@helper Script(string scriptName, UrlHelper url)
{
    <script src="@url.Content(string.Format("~/Scripts/{0}", scriptName))" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's important to understand that the call `$('#_compGrid').jqGrid({...});` **converts** initial empty `<table id="_compGrid"></table>` element to relatively complex structure of dives and tables. So you can do such call **only once**. Such call *creates and initialize the grid*. In other words the function `showGrid` has bad name. The function can be called *only once*. The second call of it will test that the grid already exist and it will do nothing. If you need to change some parameters of existing grid you can use `setGridParam` method.

In the case you can use absolutely another solution to block the grid. After the call `$('#_compGrid').jqGrid({...});` the DOM element of the initial table get some expandos - new property or method. For example `$('#_compGrid')[0]` will contains `grid` property which contains `beginReq` and `endReq` methods. So you can first create the grid (in the `showGrid` function) and include options `loadui: 'block'` and `loadtext: 'Processing...'` in the list of options which you use. Then if you need to block the grid later you can use

```js
$('#_compGrid')[0].grid.beginReq();
```

and the code

```js
$('#_compGrid')[0].grid.endReq();
```

to remove blocking. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BlockGrid.htm) which demonstrates this. Alternatively you can show overlays created by jqGrid manually like I described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2706447/315935). The code will be simple enough:

```js
var gridId = "_compGrid"; // id of the grid
...
$("#lui_" + gridId).show();
$("#load_" + gridId).text("Processing...").show();
```

to show the overlay and

```js
$("#lui_" + gridId).hide();
$("#load_" + gridId).hide();
```

to hide the overlay. See [another demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/BlockGrid1.htm) which works exactly like the first one.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any plugin. Just add/remove css:

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  //optional
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9WhdS/9/)

Comment: This doesn't work in IE (at least in v 11)  with the checkboxes